# jQuery Page Background Fading

Tags: jquery, background, fade

I have 2 background images (on the body of the page), both the same except that one is brighter (higher opacity). I'm trying to figure out how I can make the two fade between each other consistently so that it looks like it's getting brighter and darker. Basically as one fades in the other fades out and then it repeats itself.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many fade-in, fade-out plugins for jQuery.  [Here](http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm) is one list.  For example, this [FadeTransition](http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=223) plugin will get you a lot of the way there - set it up with the two images you want in a div with a z-index that will make them the background of your page and they will keep fading to each other.